# Node.js convention for naming

Tags: node.js

With regard to Node.js, is there a convention for naming arguments for a function that serves as a constructor.

For example, we might have:

```
var classVar1;
var classVar2;

exports.init = function init(classVar1_in, classVar2_in){

classVar1 = classVar1_in;
classVar2 = classVar2_in;

return {
//something
}
}
```

I am looking for something better than the above :) I am using ESLint, but I don't see anything there to enforce a convention like this (as it's not really possible to do this in JS without using even more conventions).

Comment: I don't know of any conventions for these particular parameters. In general you want variables to be no longer than necessary and no shorter than necessary

Comment: well my current convention is to make the constructor args as ugly as mfing possible so it's extremely obvious.

Comment: yeah I think its a little too much. If we had a person consctructor I'd declare it like so `function person(name, age, sex, address, ...){/* ... */}`

Comment: I'm not to speaking for Node.js in particular, but you could prefix the private variables with an underscore, like `_classVar1`, or put them in an object so later on you're setting `obj.classVar1 = classVar1;`

Comment: well, it's kind of hard to explain but WebStorm puts an underline under local variables that are used (as opposed to unused) so prefixing with an underscore doesn't help because the underscore invisible due to the underline. I don't think it's a bad idea to use an object for "class" variables, maybe will try that sometime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good convention I've often seen, including in Node programs:

> http://www.j-io.org/Javascript-Naming_Conventions/
>
> A constructor function starting with new should always start with a
>   capital letter
>
> ```
> // bad example
> var test = new application();
>
> // good example
> var test = new Application();
> ```

Here is a more complete example, including constructor (1st letter upper-case) and arguments (1st letter lower-case, like all variables):

[Essential Node.js: patterns and snippets](http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/02/essential-node-js-patterns-and-snippets/)

```
// Constructor
var Class = function(value1, value2) {
  this.value1 = value1;
}
...

// properties and methods
Class.prototype = {
  value1: "default_value",
  method: function(argument) {
    this.value2 = argument + 100;
  }
};
...

// node.js module export
module.exports = Class;
...

// constructor call    
var object = new Class("Hello", "2");
```

Comment: one upvote but it doesn't answer the question exactly